# How can I import libraries in PythonAnywhere and use them in a Python notebook?

Tags: pythonanywhere

I'm both updating and installing packages/libaries, but are only able to use them through the Python3.6 console.

```
10:40 ~ $ pip3.6 install -U --user scikit-learn                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.11.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn)
Requirement already up-to-date: joblib>=0.11 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn)
Requirement already up-to-date: scipy>=0.17.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn)
```

When using pip install it fails with :

```
10:40 ~ $ pip install -U --user scikit-learn                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/18/28/5a48b00599b476875415b97bdfdb3849bafb31183c1d785501dbc8a77aa2/scikit-learn-0.22.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-JYw8w1/scikit-learn/setup.py", line 47, in <module>
        import sklearn
      File "sklearn/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
        from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
      File "sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
        raise_build_error(e)
      File "sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 41, in raise_build_error
        %s""" % (e, local_dir, ''.join(dir_content).strip(), msg))
    ImportError: No module named _check_build
    ___________________________________________________________________________
    Contents of sklearn/__check_build:
    __init__.py               _check_build.pyx          __init__.pyc
    setup.py
    ___________________________________________________________________________
    It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

    If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
    to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
    `make` in the source directory.

    It appears that you are importing a local scikit-learn source tree. For
    this, you need to have an inplace install. Maybe you are in the source
    directory and you need to try from another location.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-JYw8w1/scikit-learn/
```

Answer (score 1):

I imported the notebook, and forgot to change Kernel Python3.6. It was still on Python3. Changed notebook to 3.6, and the it used the updated libary's-

Answer (score 0):

When you run `pip` on PythonAnywhere, outside virtual environment, it installs packages for `python2`. The latest version of `scikit-learn` to work with `python2` is 0.20.4. So, install it with `pip install scikit-learn==0.20.4`

You tried to install 0.22.1 with `python2`.

Comment: I got error, allready installed. Added --upgrade and got this error msg:
RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required.

Comment: If 0.20.4 is already installed, you need to use it if you want to stick to python2. No need to install anything and no way to upgrade under python2.

Comment: I'm using Python3

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, when you run pip on PythonAnywhere, outside virtual environment, it installs packages for python2.

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed a package using `pip3.6`, make sure that your kernel version for your notebook is 3.6 -- if it's (say) 3.7, then it won't work, because each version of Python has its own separate set of installed modules.